# Android - Wifimanager handle wifi-connection states

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I've got an app which connect itself programatically to a wifi connection. My problem is, I want to handle the case, that the password is wrong. I want to detect that the password is not correct in runtime. To be precise I've got a progressdialog running while the connection is established, so if the password is wrong the progressdialog is just shown all the time and can't be skipped. A further note: I handled a password which is less than 8 characters by using this code:

```
if(!m_wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)) {
            progressDialogConnecting.dismiss();
            createInfoMessageDialog(CONST.WIFI_CON_FAILED_TITLE, CONST.WIFI_CON_FAILED_MSG_CONFAILURE);
            m_wifiManager.reconnect();
            return;
        }
```

If the key for the wifi connection is less than 8 characters, this if-case gets triggered. But if it is longer than 8 characters and wrong I get an endless state of showing the progress dialog.
What I exactly want to ask: how do I handle 1. wrong password 2. connection states (just like Android system showing me the toasts "Connected to Wifi xyz") ? AND is it even possible to handel the first one (wrong password)?

Here is the code, that did not work for handling connection established event (this is just the wifirecevier, I also registered it in the activity):

```
 public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)){
                            if(wrongNetworkConnected)
                            progressDialogConnecting.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: What I am currently doing, is that I have a Handler which tells me to whom I am connected. That's useful because I can say that after the reconnect() I am reconnected to the old network (current network) and not the new one - so apparently the password could be wrong (or something else), because I could not connect to the new network.

The problem about this method is that first of all it takes too much time and secondly it is not reliable. I can lie and say that if you will get reconnected to your current network it is the fault of a wrong password, but actually it is not 100% sure that you cannot reconnect because of this - it may also have other reasons. So I am still searching for a simple feedback/handle from the suplicant that the password is wrong, just like the android api does in the wifi settings of each android device...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is, I want to handle the case, that the password is wrong.

After some research I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466748/wifi-authentication-error-in-android) which is not marked as answered but it still worked for me very well.

Here is the if-case in which the program jumps (already tested several times by me) if there is an authentication error --> e.g. wrong password:

```
int supl_error=intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR, -1);

if(supl_error==WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING){
          // DO SOMETHING 
}
```

*NOTE:* As seen in the linked post above this if-case should appear in a `BroadcastReceiver` adding the intent `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`to the receiver-registration in your activity-class.

Comment: just wanted your help if possible, i am stuck in the same situation and the problem is EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR has been deprecated. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

'EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR' is deprecated as of API 28: Android 9.0 (Pie). If you use WifiNetworkSuggestion to connect to Wifi, use WifiManager.SuggestionConnectionStatusListener. Override onConnectionStatus method in it and check if failureReason equals to WifiManager.STATUS_SUGGESTION_CONNECTION_FAILURE_AUTHENTICATION.

```
WifiManager.SuggestionConnectionStatusListener mSuggestionConnectionStatusListener = new WifiManager.SuggestionConnectionStatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStatus(@NonNull WifiNetworkSuggestion wifiNetworkSuggestion, int failureReason) {
        switch (failureReason) {
                case WifiManager.STATUS_SUGGESTION_CONNECTION_FAILURE_AUTHENTICATION:
                // authentification handling code here
                break;
    }
};
```